# Display real time server process name to acknowledge to user in PHP without ajax

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, alert, simplemodal

I have a joomla website with Virtuemart payments. There is form at my checkout page and during form submission form redirect to another page.

I have requirement like, from checkout page when user click on order now button I have to display real time process name of backend on the screen, Like, if order has been creating it has to show message "Order has been creating" and so on.

I tried and apply simple JavaScript Alert at PHP functions,

```
e.g. echo "<script>alert('Order has been creating');</script>";
```

but all alerts display at destination page after completion of server process.

I have also tried

```
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(5);
```

to display alert message from PHP function on the screen, but it also not working.

Is there any possible way to show Modal or alert on the screen during execution of PHP function at server without use of ajax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the goal is to keep the user on a usable UI while something happens in the background then AJAX is really the way to go.  Is there a specific reason to avoid it?

Comment: In my website, while form submits, virtuemart start performing all default process on page reload, so I can implement Ajax for tracking process in Virtumart Joomla.

Comment: What @David said, and also, do the "stages of ordering" really take long enough for this to make sense? If your back-end needs _seconds_ to process an order, you may want to instead focus your efforts on providing a quicker response. The whole process should be done and finished by the time the user has the time to read "Order has been creating"...

Comment: @AshishPatel: *"performing [...] on page reload"* - That may be a misinterpretation of the technical details. Though admittedly I'm not familiar with this "Virtumart" product.  But perhaps Markus' comment above is onto something... Maybe the processing should be moved offline entirely. In your system you can quickly accept the *request* for processing and store the details of that request, then immediately direct the user to a page indicating that their request has been received and will be processed. Though there's no reason not to do *that* with AJAX. Then "process" it in a background system

Comment: Maybe the folks at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange will understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

After submission of form and page start redirecting/reloading, request send to server and **we can not get real time status of information processing on server  to display for user on browser on same time**. Once response receive from server we can display server information and acknowledge user on browser.

**Note:**
Process via Ajax is Only way to display real time status of server to acknowledge user on browser.